# how do i write a constraint and the sum of the z value?

Tags: matlab, matrix, constraints

i have the code and i try to make x as constraint but when i run i always get an error said that Undefined function or variable 'x'. below is the code and how can i get the sum of the z value?

```
clc;
clear;

%sum sum sum sum(fik*djq*xij*xkq)
%i,k= facilities
%j,q= location
%f(i,k)= flow between facilities i and k
%d(j,q)= distance between locations j and q
%xij = 1 if facility i is assigned to location j and if otherwise, xij = 0


% Flow matrix: flow assigning facility i (column) to facility k (row)

f = [0 5 7 9;
     5 0 4 6;
     7 4 0 3;
     9 6 3 0];

%Distance matrix: distance assigning location j (column) to location q (row)

d = [0 6 8 9;
     6 0 5 1;
     8 5 0 2;
     9 1 2 0];

z= 0;
nf= 4;%no of facilities
nd= 4;%no of locations 

for i=1:nf 
    for j=1:nf 
        for k=1:nd 
            for q=1:nd 
                z = min('z','sum(sum(f(i,k)*d(j,q)*x(i,j)*x(k,q)))');
                %if x(i,j)==1;
                %else x(k,q)==0;
            end
        end
    end
end

%Constraints 
%x as binary 0 1, 
%x(i,j) = 1 if facility i is assigned to location j 0r otherwise, x(i,j) = 0

Constraints.constr1 = (x(i,j))==1;

%The first set of constraints requires that each facility gets exactly one 
%location, that is for each facility, the sum of the location values 
%corresponding to that facility is exactly one

Constraints.constr2 = sum(x,2) == 1;

%The second set of constraints are inequalities. These constraints specify 
%that each office has no more than one facility in it.

Constraints.constr3 = sum(x,1) == 1;

disp (z);
```

are the constraint i code is wrong?

Comment: You get that error message because you haven’t declared `x`. You declare `f` and `d`, you need a similar statement for `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the attached code, as I can see, you are using matrix `x` 4 times.
The first use is inside the for-loops and other 3 uses are the one-liners following the loops.

First of all, I suspect you have used function min() in a wrong way. As the arguments should not be characters. Remove '' and use the following line:

```
z = min(z,sum(sum(f(i,k)*d(j,q)*x(i,j)*x(k,q))));
```

Now, coming to your question, you have not told what are the contents of your matrix x, so the code doesn't know what value is stored at say, x(1,1) or x(2,3).

It is, therefore, expected to throw an error.

Comment: x value is depend on the value of f(i,k) and d(j, q)..for example if in matrix flow(i1,k2)=5(value in the matix),and dis(j2,q1)=6(value in the matrix), so x(i,j) will be x(i1,j2) and x(k, q) will be x(k2,q1) and the value of x either will be 1 or 0.

Comment: If you are thinking that Constraints.constr1 = (x(i,j))==1; sets a literal constraint upon the content of matrix x, then it is not so. You need to manually define your logic in the code using say, if-else condition or using functions.

Comment: I'll like to point out one more thing that you mentioned i=(column) and k=(row) and at a later instance you are calling matrix content as f(i,k), but the first argument represents rowno. and second one represents columnno. In this code, it doesn't matter anyways because the matrices f and d are symmetric.

Comment: before i have done that but which is define my logic but it didnt give me the answer i want so i try using constraint...

Comment: the thing is how do i write so that the matrix can be read as f(i,k)? i have been searching for example for that and i didnt find it